# Pyinstaller exe not working on other computer(with other windows ver.)

Tags: python

My platform is Windows 10 and Python 3.9. There is another computer(Windows server 2008R2) without Python. So I'd like to use `pyinstaller` in my computer and use `.exe` on the other computer.

I tried simple script `print("hello")` and used `pyinstaller -F myscript.py`

`.exe` works on my computer, but failed on the other computer.

**Error**
`error loading python dll ~ python39.dll`

Should I use Python 3.8? Or what should I do?

Comment: check the operative system type, if I remember very well if it's a 32bit and your program is 64bit it can't be open. Ensure that you create a 32bit version so it can be run on both pc even if they have different CPU

Comment: both are 64bit. but i will check again and try it, thanks.

Comment: let me know in case, in the past I had the same problem ;)

Comment: pyinstaller is a pain. It didn't work last time I tried it. I used cx_Freeze and it worked perfectly. Carry on using pyinstaller if you want, but try to find an alternative if things don't work out.

Comment: ok, i will try cx_Freeze tomorrow. i hope it works.... thanks for recommend!!

Comment: take a look at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files

Comment: I am also facing same problem .I created exe with lenovo machine and run on mi machine it works and i tried another lenovo machine it's giving below error.                                                                          File "cv2\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
                                                                           
from .cv2 import *

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I resolved the problem regarding above my comment! i just install lower version python and run the exe finally it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Pyinstaller does not create fully standalone executables, it creates dependencies (E.g. this python39.dll), so this python39.dll should be on the computer which is running this executable. Because python is already installed on your computer, python39.dll is already there and everything works fine. The problem is that machine that you're running this program on probably won't have it.

To fix this there are several solutions:

1. Install python 3.9 on targets' machine (But in this case you don't need to create an executable)
2. Include python39.dll with your program

For second solution just create a folder and move your executable into it as well as this python39.dll library. Windows will find it because it's in the same directory where this executable is. You can get this library from *c:\Windows\System32* folder (Or where all DLL's are stored on your system) and then just copy it into folder with your executable. After that ship not just executable but this folder with library included.

@Stepan wrote in comments that you can also include this library right in your executable by adding **--add-binary "path\to\python39.dll"** to your command when compiling. The final command will look like this:

**pyinstaller -F --add-binary "c:\Windows\System32\python39.dll" myscript.py**

Comment: Actually. it isn't true: pyinstaller does produces such executables which are working on the absolutely "Python-free" computers.

Comment: ```pyinstaller -F --add-binary "c:\Windows\System32\python39.dll;." myscript.py``` after adding **;.** helped

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Python version is compatible with the windows version you are trying to use. I was having this problem with an exe I did using Python 3.10. Did it again with Python 3.7 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it could be a solution to use something like auto-py-to-exe wrap for pyistaller: it knows better which option to set for py converting :)
Also, from my exp, in some cases you should modify yout already normally working from terminal Py code before pyinstaller: for example replace `exit()` with `sys.exit()` and so on.