# Pyinstaller Error - "Windows cannot access the specified the specified device, path, "

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hello Everyone since today morning whatever the files i have created using pyinstaller are not opening -  after clicking on the exe created i am getting the error **`"Windows cannot access the specified the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."`**

though the same files were working fine till yesterday can anyone kindly guide what maybe the issue here or how can i fix it

```
Python ver - 3.8.10
Pyinstaller tried with 4.5.1 & 4.7
OS - Win 10
```

Comment: I recommend to check the file permissions or whether the antivirus is blocking your file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error opening python executable in Windows after using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958234/error-opening-python-executable-in-windows-after-using-pyinstaller)